# The Lord of the Puzzles

Tags: rebus, no-computers

In 1904 (at the age of 12) J.R.R. Tolkien sent a "puzzle letter" (pictured below) to a family friend; Father Francis Morgan.

**What does it say?**

<sup><sub>Obviously it would be trivially simple to google the answer, so I want you to **promise me** that you didn't :-)</sub></sup>

[image]

Comment: It's so tempting to Google it! But I _won't_ <grits teeth>

Comment: Is this the complete letter, or is there more below what you've included?

Comment: @randal'thor - Apparently, there's a page 2. You'll need to go to the Bodleian library to read it.

Comment: Well, I'm several hours' drive away from the Bodleian library! But thanks - now I know it's OK to end in mid-sentence. I was trying to fit the last 2 pictures to "Ronald" or some kind of signature...

Comment: I will quite happily offer a 500 rep bounty for visiting the Bodleian and posting the second page :-)

Comment: Will that offer still be open in a few months' time? 500 rep is not to be sniffed at!

Comment: @randal'thor - It's an open offer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The sender's address (top right) was:

> **Woodside House, Rednal** (wood, S, eye, D=500, E, house, {N, A, L=50} in red)

The letter reads:

> **My dear wise owl Fr. Francis,** (M=1000, eye, deer, Y's, owl, France with 'Fr.' on it, hiss)
>  **You are too bad** (U, R, 2, bee, A, D=500)
>  **not to come in** (knot, 2, sea, O, M=1000, E, inn)
>  **spite of Fr. Dennis.** (spit, E, OF, Fr., D=500, hen, eye, S)
>  **I am so sorry you** (Hyam, sew, saw, rye, yew)
>  **did not like the** (D=500, eye, D, knot, L=50, bike-B, tea, HE)
>  **word 'piano' in my l...** (words, pea, note-T, inn, M, eye, L)
>  **...ast letter. So I...** (mast-M, letter, sow, eye)

Thanks to **Pete** and **d'alar'cop** and **LeppyR64** and **JNF** for help with some of the clues (see comments below).

Comment: I included a clue in the question about what France relates to.

Comment: @Richard God, I'm stupid! Fixed now. Is NAL right?

Comment: Not a clue. I've only googled it to the extent that I've found that an answer exists. I've not actually read it.

Comment: @rand al'thor Your leaf looks like peas to me. The second to last image looks like a man sowing seeds

Comment: @Pete Thanks - so the last couple of pictures could be "So I", assuming that's not the entire letter (it'd be very short if so!). I agree on peas, but not sure how to incorporate a P in there...

Comment: The outfitter is a tailor.  The image after it is someone sewing.

Comment: The tree is shaped which is usually called a topiary.  The stave I think could refer to the sixteenth rest.  Rest - t = res?

Comment: How about (following the "PEA") "NOTE" - "T" = "NOE" giving "PEANOE" - PIANO? Also how about HYAM = I AM?

Comment: I am makes sense and then the grass is probably "rye". I am so sorry making the topiary yew for you.

Comment: @LeppyR64 AHA, yew! I was trying to make it fit ewe ... seems obvious now!

Comment: I want to say that the little book is "word" but it's tough to say without the context of either the previous letter or the continuation on the second page.

Comment: @Richard I think it's complete now.

Comment: I'd say Snake is **hiss**ing

Comment: Great job, rand!

Comment: @jnf - I agree. It's France-Hiss = Francis

Comment: Don't like the "word" either. Maybe it's a story? Or a book-leaf?

Comment: I've fairly sure that's a stave, minus a "t" = save