# The Lord of the Puzzles (pt II)

Tags: rebus

Given the modest interest in the question [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15763/the-lord-of-the-puzzles), I thought you might enjoy another of J.R.R Tolkien's rebus letters, this one written at the tender age of 11.

This one is (in theory) slightly easier to decipher but alas the image quality is slightly lower:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some assistance from [this thread](http://www.thehalloffire.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12), here is an explanation.  Upgrades are welcome.

**Left side of page:**

> **Am sending you one all** (ham (s+end in g) u 1 awl)
> **pictures.** (pea+eye+sea+tea+ures.)
> **We each have** (we a+ech hay+ve)
> **found two lovely** (f+hound-h 2 (50=L+dove-d+50=L+y))
> **walks to take you** (wall+keys-ey 2 t+ache u)
> **when you do! Come** (w+hen yew 500=D+o! Comb-b)
> **out here which we hope** (ou+tea h+ear witch we h+pop-p+e)
> **will be soon.** (w+ill bee s+moon-m).

**Right side of page:**

> **Your loving** (Wye+hour-h l+oven+ing)
> **Ronald** (R on a+50=L+d)
>
> Please enquire for "? at Woodside Cottage Rednal. JR T??
>
> There was an old priest named Francis
> Who was so fond of chiffony dances
> That he sat up too late
> And worried his pate
> Arranging these Frenchified Prances
>
> (This is to pay you out for not coming: sending Father Edmund instead)

Comment: Thought I'd done it :-)

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer:

> **line 4**: Found 2 lovely (F from previous line, Hound-H, 2, L=50, Dove-D, L=50, Y)
>  **line 5**: Walks to T(?) you (Wall, KEY - EY, 2 T (Tell/Take - can't figure out), U) 
>  **line 6**: When you do! (W, hen, yew, D=500, O!) 
>  **last line**": the last two words seem to me like be visitor (Bee, **wiz**ard,storm-M)

Still working on the remaining words.

Comment: Partial answers need love too. Upvoted :-)